# Can custom tokens be used in Link data fields?

Tags: links

I want to create a custom field of type 'link'. Inserted into the link is a custom field token ({contact.custom_n}). I also want this link to open in a new window. I have tried to use the 'link' data field but that does not appear to resolve the token and cannot display in a new window. I then tried to create the link in a Rich Text field but that did not resolve either (although the link can open in a new window)
Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Martin, i don't quite follow what you are trying to achieve as the outcome.

Comment: We maintain contact records of rugby union players. They are registered with the ARU and the ARU runs its own website. Each player has a Rugby ID. We store the RugbyID on our website. In each contact record I want to show a link which will automatically link to the contact's record on the ARU website. To do that I need to include in the URL to link to the ARU website the Rugby ID of the particular contact. I therefore need to include a custom field token in the link. I can do that by including {contact.custom_n} in the URL where n is the ID of the custom field. The token does not resolve.

Comment: Drupal? if so you could do it via a Block sitting above or beside the civi record

Comment: I want to return to this issue since it is something that will provide us with some efficiency. Peter from Fusion suggested that I achieve my goal (I am using Drupal) by using a block. I have been trying to work out how to do this and have failed. Is it possible to get a little more information to put me on the right track to solve this issue?

Comment: You will need some php in a module that will look for the cid in the url and then display the block with the relevant info based on a Contextual Filter. I do not think this is something you can do via the UI